# Background image doesn't show for header

Tags: html, css, background-image

I have simple html page with `body` and `header elements`:

```
<body>
    <header class="logoBar"></header>
</body>
```

I try to add background image to `header`. If i do:

```
.logoBar {
   background:url('http://img704.imageshack.us/img704/2162/67726065.jpg') repeat-x center top;
}
```

It doesn't show image. But if i make:

```
body {
    background:url('http://img704.imageshack.us/img704/2162/67726065.jpg') repeat-x center top;
}
```

I see image. Why doesn't it work for `header`?

Thank you.

Comment: What browser are you trying to look at this in? As IE6, 7 and 8 are not able to show HTML5 elements without some additional javascript. Also you may need to add a width and height to your logobar class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting a width and height on your header element's css.

```
.logoBar {
   width: 100%;
   height: 250px; <!-- Your image height goes here...
   background:url('http://img704.imageshack.us/img704/2162/67726065.jpg') repeat-x center top;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to set a `width` and `height` for the header. If it has no content it will simply be 0px wide and 0px tall.

```
.logoBar {
   background:url('http://img704.imageshack.us/img704/2162/67726065.jpg') repeat-x center top;
   width: 900px;
   height: 300px;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Zjczp/

Answer (score 0):

now define value of your class `.logobar`

**as like this**

```
.logobar{display:block;}
```

and define `width` and `height` **according to** `@WDffy` and `@Cristy`